# Drag and Drop between 2 listboxs & Database Update

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, drag-and-drop

I want to implement a facility for a web app users for drag an item from a listbox and drop it to the other listbox. After every Drag & Drop needs to update a sql table. I googled about D&D and find some solutions, but I do not know which one is the best? and also I do not know the right way. Which on I have to use? jquery, Ajax, or some other plugins? 
I'd appreciate If someone give me a pathway to accomplish this task.

**Edited:**
I found out I have to use ListView instead of Listbox, because of my need to server side control.

**Edited**
[A sample with ListView](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETDragItemInListView-4dd39428)

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/ is one proven solution for that.

Comment: @Rudi tnx. I know that, but I want to find out different solutions and then select one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done the above task by googling in stackoverflow.com and other weblogs . I found different ways to do that. And finally it's been finished. I post this answer for whom maybe needs this solution in the future.

1-Html code:

```
    <div class="drag_container">
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" Style="width: 200px;">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <ul id="tempdd" class="connectedSortable">
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </ul>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li class="ui-state-default" id='<%# Eval("id")%>'><%# Eval("id")%> +_+ <%#Eval("Name")%></li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>


    <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" Style="width: 200px;">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <ul id="tempdd1" class="connectedSortable">
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </ul>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li class="ui-state-highlight" id='<%# Eval("id")%>'><%# Eval("id")%> +_+ <%#Eval("Name")%></li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>

</div>
```

2-Css:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    #tempdd, #tempdd1 {
        list-style-type: none;
        border-right: #eee 2px solid;
        padding-right: 25px;
        border-top: #eee 2px solid;
        padding-left: 25px;
        float: left;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
        margin: 3px;
        border-left: #eee 2px solid;
        width: 200px;
        padding-top: 25px;
        border-bottom: #eee 2px solid;
        min-height: 20px;
    }

        #tempdd li, #tempdd1 li {
            padding-right: 2px;
            padding-left: 2px;
            font-size: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 2px;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding-top: 2px;
            font-family: verdana, tahoma, arial;
            background-color: #eee;
            height: 20px;
        }

    .highlight {

    }
</style>
```

3-Javascript: SaveDragDropItem method has 3 parameters: dragged item, source listview(table), destination listview(table). I used the last two parameters in data layer for identifying that the item removed from which table and added to which table!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var dragged = null;
    var parent = null;
    var inserterId = null;
    $(function () {
        $("#tempdd, #tempdd1").sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
            //placeholder: "highlight",
            scroll: false,
            delay:1000,
            axis: "x",
            start: function (e, ui) { 
                // modify ui.placeholder however you like
                ui.placeholder.html("I'm modifying the placeholder element!");
            },
            update: function (event, ui) {
                var serve = JSON.stringify({ ItemId: dragged, Source: parent, Destination: $(this).attr('id') });
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/WebServices/GeneralWebService.asmx/SaveDragDropItem",
                    data: serve,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (r) {
                        inserterId = r.d;
                        OnSuccess(dragged, inserterId.toString());
                        dragged = null;
                        parent = null;
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Server Error!!");
                        dragged = null;
                        parent = null;
                    }
                });
            }
        }).disableSelection();

        function OnSuccess(i, inserterId) {
            $('#' + i).attr('id', inserterId);

        }
        $("li").draggable({
            connectToSortable: '#tempdd, #tempdd1',
            revert: "invalid",
            cursor: "move",
            containment: '#drag_container',
            start: function (event, ui) {
                dragged = $(this).attr('id');
                parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                dragged = $(this).attr('id');
                parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
            }
        });

    })
</script>
```

4-Code behind:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim oDragDrop As New DragDrop_BL ' DragDrop_BL is a class in Business layer.

    Dim dt As DataTable = oDragDrop.GetDataFirst()

    ListView1.DataSource = dt
    ListView1.InsertItemPosition = IIf(dt.Rows.Count = 0, InsertItemPosition.LastItem, InsertItemPosition.None)

    ListView1.DataBind()

    dt = oDragDrop.GetDataSecond()
    ListView2.DataSource = dt
    ListView2.InsertItemPosition = IIf(dt.Rows.Count = 0, InsertItemPosition.LastItem, InsertItemPosition.None)
    ListView2.DataBind()


End Sub
```

5-Webservice method:

```
    <WebMethod()> _
Public Function SaveDragDropItem(ByVal ItemId As Integer, Source As String, Destination As String) As Integer
    Dim oDragDrop As New DragDrop_BL ' DragDrop_BL is a class in Business layer. The method save dragged item in Database
    SaveDragDropItem = oDragDrop.SaveDragDropItem(ItemId, Source, Destination)
    oDragDrop = Nothing
End Function
```

6-BL:

```
    Function SaveDragDropItem(ItemId As Integer, Source As String, Destination As String) As Integer
    Dim oDragDrop_DL As New DragDrop_DL
    SaveDragDropItem = oDragDrop_DL.SaveDragDropItem(ItemId, Source, Destination)
    oDragDrop_DL = Nothing
End Function
```

7-DL:

```
    Function SaveDragDropItem(ItemId As Integer, Source As String, Destination As String) As Integer
    Dim cm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
    Dim cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection
    Dim p As SqlParameter = Nothing
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing

    Dim strSQL As String = String.Empty
    Dim Description As String = String.Empty


    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[" + Source + "] Where id= " & ItemId

    cn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
    cn.Open()
    cm.CommandText = strSQL
    cm.Connection = cn
    da.SelectCommand = cm
    dt = New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    cn.Close()

    Try
        strSQL = ""
        strSQL = " INSERT INTO  dbo.[" + Destination + "] "
        strSQL &= " ([name], [email], [address]) "
        strSQL &= " VALUES "
        strSQL &= " (@name, @email, @address); Select @Ident = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); "
        strSQL &= " Delete dbo.[" + Source + "] Where id= " & ItemId


        p = New SqlParameter("name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)
        p.Value = dt.Rows(0)("name")
        cm.Parameters.Add(p)
        p = New SqlParameter("email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)
        p.Value = dt.Rows(0)("email")
        cm.Parameters.Add(p)
        p = New SqlParameter("address", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1000)
        p.Value = dt.Rows(0)("address")
        cm.Parameters.Add(p)


        p = New SqlParameter("Ident", SqlDbType.Int)
        p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        cm.Parameters.Add(p)

        cn.ConnectionString = Me.ConnectionString
        cn.Open()
        cm.CommandText = strSQL
        cm.Connection = cn
        cm.Transaction = cn.BeginTransaction
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        SaveDragDropItem = cm.Parameters("Ident").Value
        If cm.Transaction IsNot Nothing Then cm.Transaction.Commit()


    Catch ex As SqlException
        If cm.Transaction IsNot Nothing Then cm.Transaction.Rollback()
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        If cm.Transaction IsNot Nothing Then cm.Transaction.Rollback()
        Throw New System.Exception("Error In " & Me.ToString() & "-->" & ex.Message)
    Finally
        cn.Close()
        cn.Dispose()
        cm.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function
```

Excuse me for my poor English. If anyone needs any comment or description about the above codes, I'll happy to help!

**Update:**
For saving all sortable lists changes in db with a single request, you  have to change javascript section to the following code:

```
        var dragged = null;
    var parent = null;
    var destination = null;
    var inserterId = null;
    var list1, list2;
    $(function () {
        $("#tempdd, #tempdd1").sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
            forcePlaceholderSize: true,
            start: function (e, ui) {
                // modify ui.placeholder however you like
                ui.placeholder.html("Drop here!");
            },
            receive: function (event, ui) {

                list1 = new Array();
                list2 = new Array();
                $("#tempdd >li").each(function () {
                    list1.push($(this).attr("id"));
                });
                $("#tempdd1 >li").each(function () {
                    list2.push($(this).attr("id"));
                });
            },
            remove: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.target == event.target) alert("Error!");
            }
        }).disableSelection();


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnUpdate").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //, Source: 'tempdd', Destination: 'tempdd1' 
                var serve = JSON.stringify({ Listf: list1.toString(), Lists: list2.toString(), Source: 'tempdd', Destination: 'tempdd1' });
                console.log(serve.toString());
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/WebServices/GeneralWebService.asmx/SaveDragDropItem",
                    data: serve,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (r) {
                        //alert("s");
                        location.reload(true);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                        alert(err.Message);
                    }
                });

            });
        });
    })
```

Comment: I think my question was clear. If you think it's not clear, maybe it's because of my English knowledge.

Comment: For saving all changes in sortable lists in db with a single request, you  have to change javascript section to the following code: